# Switch display after switching camera in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got script created for Unity, which switches active camera with C button and it looks like that:

```
void Start(){
        currentCameraIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < cameras.Length; i++){
            cameras[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);}
        if (cameras.Length > 0){
            cameras[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);}}

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)){
            currentCameraIndex++;
            if (currentCameraIndex < cameras.Length){
                cameras[currentCameraIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                cameras[currentCameraIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);}
            else{
                cameras[currentCameraIndex - 1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                currentCameraIndex = 0;
                cameras[currentCameraIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }}}
```

It does change the camera on button, but the display doesn't switch automatically - I can do it manually only.

Is there a way to change display according to the camera change? I was looking for the solution and saw some videos, where the display was changing due to camera, but couldn't find a way to do this on my project.. 
[Display Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNMmM.png)

Comment: what is the type of the `cameras` variable?

Comment: its: public Camera[] cameras

Comment: Try using `cameras[xyz].enabled = true;` and `cameras[xyz.enabled = false;` instead of `cameras[xyz].gameObject.SetActive(true);` and `cameras[xyz.gameObject.SetActive(false);`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it gives me the same effect

Comment: Okay, I've already solved it.. I've set different displays for camera and it should be set to the Display 1. I'm quite new to Unity so that's something I wasn't aware of, but your question made me think about it.. its solved, thanks and sorry <facepalm>

Comment: Glad I could help! Please feel to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) by explaining what you did as an answer below.